# Is there any disadvantage to referencing modules through `core` instead of `std`?

Tags: rust

Rust's standard library is exposed as two packages: `std` and `core`. In terms of API, the functionality in `core` is the subset of `std` that can be supported without depending on any operating system integration or heap allocation. When writing imports for my libraries, I've been tempted to always refer to modules via the more-compatible `core` instead of `std`, if they're available in both.

However, it's been unclear to me whether their implementations of the same functionality could vary. If I use `core::cell::RefCell`, could I get an implementation that's less efficient than if I'd referred to `std::cell::RefCell`?

Is there any disadvantage to referencing modules through `core` instead of `std` if they're available in both?

Comment: There are related clippy lints: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/7724

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust aims to be a general purpose language that can run on many kinds of architectures (x86_64, i686, PowerPC, ARM, RISC-V) and systems (Windows, macOS, Linux) and even embedded systems with no [**O**perating **S**ystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).

But when you don't have an OS, you don't necessarily have a memory allocator or file handling, because those are things a OS would normally do.

This is where `#![no_std]` comes into play. If you put that directive in your *lib.rs*, you will tell the Rust compiler to not link the `std` crate, but only use `core` instead. As you said, `core` is a subset of `std` and has (mostly) everything that does not require allocation of memory or other things that require an underlying OS.

There is no difference in the actual implementation though. If the function is provided in `core`, the function in `std` is just an [reexport](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/lib.rs.html#374).

TL;DR: Use `std` if you have an Operating System running, else use `core`. There is no need to mix them.

Comment: I agree with most of your explanation, but not your conclusion. Most people should use `std` instead of `core`, unless they are deliberately attempting to create code that should work in a no-std environment.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't see how my conclusion differs from yours ^^ Do you want me to expand it?

Comment: This does not answer whether there is a "disadvantage to referencing modules through core instead of std" or not. To me it seems like referencing core program elements via std only obscures the parts of the code that use std-specific parts and, therefore, require an OS.

Comment: @ValentinKovalenko feel free to add your own answer ;)

Comment: I don't think I know enough to have an answer. But I will enable the relevant Clippy lints (github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/7724) in my projects when they become available in 1.64.

Comment: `There is no need to mix them.` well, using `core` up front might make it easier to migrate your crate to `no_std` later on.